# Date Range Mongo Query using Meteor Js

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an attribute in my collection called `dateacquired` and the date is formatted like: `2014-03-28 06:08:00`.

I am needing to pull back all documents in my collection that are less than or equal to a month ago from the current date. I am just not sure how to write this query.

Anyone know how to start one something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume those dates are stored as strings? You can compare strings with the mongoDB comparison operators [`$gt`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) or [`$lt`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) and they work as you’d expect. I’m going to also use [Sugar](http://sugarjs.com/) to make my life easier (highly recommended; add via [`mrt add sugarjs`](https://atmospherejs.com/package/sugarjs)) which gives me the `Date.create` and `Date.format` methods which reduce this into a one-liner:

```
  var cursorOfDocumentsSinceOneMonthAgo = yourCollection.find({
    dateacquired:
      { $gt: Date.create("1 month ago").format("{yyyy}-{MM}-{dd} {hh}:{mm}:{ss}")
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

My meteor method for how many people have signed up in the last nDays:

```
userCountPreviousDays: function (nDays) {
    check(nDays, Number);

    var arr = [];

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var msInDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    for (var i = 0; i < nDays; i++) {
      arr[i] = Meteor.users.find({
        createdAt: {
          $lt: new Date(now - (msInDay * i)),
          $gt: new Date(now - (msInDay * (i+1)))
        }
      }).count();
    };

    return arr;
}
```

`arr[i]` is how many people signed up `i` days ago.